# Get the AssemblyFileVersion from GetReferencedAssemblies

Tags: .net, sharepoint, powershell

I'm trying to find, using Powershell, the AssemblyFileVersion of a deployed Sharepoint solution.

So far I manage to find that info about the solution itself, but now I'm trying to find the same about it's references.

Is there a way to get that data.

Here's my code so far

```
$assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("<AssemblyName>")
$fvi = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($assembly.Location)
Write-Host "File Version Number " $fvi.ProductVersion

$references = $assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();
foreach ($ref in $references)
{
    Write-Host $ref.Version
}
```

The $ref.Version returns the AssemblyVersion which is not the same.

I tryed the same approach (`[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName`) but it does not work. I'm gessing that the fact that this is a sharepoint solution as an impact on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for a solution and find `ReflectionOnlyLoad` method which might help you.

```
$processed = @{}
function writeAssemblyFileVersions {
  param($parentAssemblyPath)
  if ($processed[$parentAssemblyPath]) {
    return
  }
  $processed.$parentAssemblyPath = 1

  $ver = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($parentAssemblyPath).ProductVersion
  $assembly = [reflection.assembly]::LoadFile($parentAssemblyPath)

  Write-Output (New-Object PsObject -Property @{Version = $ver; Assembly = $assembly})
  foreach($a in $assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()) {
    $aForLocation = [Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoad($a.FullName)
    writeAssemblyFileVersions $aForLocation.Location
  }
}

###### sample
$loc = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms").Location
writeAssemblyFileVersions $loc |   
  Select Version, {$_.Assembly.ManifestModule.Name}
```

It recursively checks for all the dependencies. The `$processed` cache is there so that it ends finally :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tryed it but it does not work. The problem is that the referenced assemblies on the Sharepoint solution dont get published to the GAC. So when ReflectionOnlyLoad hits them their not there, is gives a "Could not load file or assembly" error. I could publish then to the GAC but I was trying to find a way to not change the existing projects

Comment: Ok, are the assemblies in a known folder? I'm asking because if you know the location, you can load them and filter only those that are referenced.

Comment: They might be, but it's probably in the criptic Sharepoint Wive

Answer (score 0):

System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute is a custom attribute. Use this API:

```
ps> $assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("<AssemblyName>")
ps> $attr = $assembly.getcustomattributes(
       [reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute])[0]
ps> $attr.version
1.0.4.1
```